# Subclass properties in a create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model like this :

```
ClassA {
 int property1;
 ClassB elementB;
}

ClassB {
  [Required]
  int nameB;
}
```

And in the view that i use to create a new A, I pass :

```
@model MyProject.ClassA
```

but i would like to have a field for ClassB like :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassB.nameB)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassB.nameB)
```

The field is displayed properly, but the Required control doesn't work, and in controller in the HttpPost action the field is always == null.
Is that the normal behaviour? 
Any idea to make it works?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

These members needs to be public property, not field. Try this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int property1 { get; set; }
    public ClassB elementB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    [Required]
    public int nameB { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ClassA a)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
}
```